# MS SSRS 2019 REST API

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Is it possible to disable the SSRS REST API? Or is it possible to only enable it for specific users.

I am conscious of the security aspect, e.g. who can do what with the API? I would not want my users connecting to certain APIs and need to be able to lock it down.

Thanks